# .htaccess and repeating a command

Tags: .htaccess

I think that this is a 'quite a basic question' but how do I allow two IP Addresses to permit entry:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
# ENTER IP HERE
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^134.139.212.198$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can I just simply copy paste the line below where it says # ENTER IP HERE

I just want to know how to do it properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just copied and paste the same line.

**Option #1: define all IP**

Here's the only way to do it:

```
Allow from 145.50.39.8
Allow from 145.50.39.9
Allow from 145.50.39.10
Allow from 145.50.39.11
Allow from 145.50.39.12
Allow from 145.50.39.13
Allow from 145.50.39.14
Allow from 145.50.39.15
Allow from 145.50.39.16
Allow from 145.50.39.17
```

**Option #2: use a partial IP**

If you want something more generic, you can use a partial IP:

```
Allow from 145.50.39
```

But this will allow IP from 145.50.39.0 to 145.50.39.255.

**Option #3: use a netmask or a CIDR**

To get even closer, you can use a netmask or a CIDR:

```
Allow from 145.50.39.0/255.255.255.224
```

or

```
Allow from 145.50.39.0/27
```

This will allow IP from 145.50.39.0 to 145.50.39.31.